# How to add multiple tool tips to a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mouseover

I've been working with a D3 svg chart with built in tool tips (using the d3-tip library I believe). The original code can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

I've successfully been able to customize it for the most part, but I need to add a second mouseover effect; so that when you mouseover a bar it not only opens the tool tip, but also another tip or layer in the upper right corner of the chart.

I tried to do something like the following, but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I just missing something in my syntax?  Or will this strategy not work at all?

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency2:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })

//adding second tool tip
var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-40, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Other Variables:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })
```

and then

```
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency2); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency2); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show, tip2.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide, tip2.hide);
```

The chart still works, but now neither tool tip shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing right now...

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show, tip2.show)
```

... will not work. In `selection.on`, the third argument is the [capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration):

> selection.on(typenames[, listener[, capture]])

Thus, the solution is wrapping both `tip` and `tip2` in another function:

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
    tip.show();
    tip2.show();
})
```

Here is a demo (hover over the circle):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 20])
  .html("<strong>Frequency2:</strong> <span style='color:red'>foo</span>")

var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([90, 20])
  .html("<strong>Other Variables:</strong> <span style='color:red'>bar</span>")

svg.call(tip)
svg.call(tip2)

d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
  tip.show();
  tip2.show();
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  tip.hide();
  tip2.hide();
});
```

```css
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="70" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo.  It seems like it should work, but I"m getting a strange error and no tool-tips are showing.  I'm seeing:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frequency2' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (svg7-2.html:105)
    at Function.tip.show (d3.tip.v0.6.3.js:33)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (svg7-2.html:152)
    at SVGRectElement.__onmouseover (d3.v3.min.js:1)`

Comment: You can see that my snippet work. So, you have a *different* problem, not related to the question you asked.

Comment: Yes, your example definitely works!  Is it possible that the data isn't accessible at that point in the execution though?  I believe the error is stating that it can't read the frequency2 variable in at that point.  Right?  Could you perhaps try your example with data included instead of the text you inserted in its place and see if it will still work?   I could also post my full code if that would help!

Comment: Please, don't edit the question: this question was already answered. Post *another* question with your *new* problem.